# How to extract grouped results from single model/table and provide to the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called `Language`, with just two columns: language and link, and would like to be able to loop through each link for each language and display in the view. i.e. (obviously this isn't code, it's just to illustrate the desired pattern)

```
Language 1
   Link 1
   Link 2
   Link 3
Language 2
   Link 1
Language 3
   Link 1
   Link 2
Language 4
etc
```

What is the 'rails way' of extracting this data, and then presenting in the view? (note: I would know how to do this easily if the data were in two different models, but it isn't)

Comment: I'm a little confused, in that you say you have `a model called Language, with just two columns: language and link`, though the example shows languages having multiple links. OK to clarify a little here please? :)

Comment: language (the column) is not unique, so 'English' might be in there 1000 times, each time with a different link

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - have popped an answer in, hope it's useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, a Railsy way would be to use the following in your controller:

```
@languages = Language.all.group_by(&:language)
```

This will give you a hash of languages grouped by the (erm...) language's language (<- perhaps rename the column to `name` to avoid this ambiguity?):

```
# { 'English' => [language_1, language_2, etc...],
#   'French' => [language_3, language_4],
#    etc... }
```

And then this in your view:

```
<% @languages.each do |language_name, languages| %>
  <h1>
    <%= language_name %>
  </h1>
  <% languages.each do |language| %>
    <p>
      <%= language.link %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Obviously the HTML tags can be whatever you'd like, though I hope that gives a useful example.

However, there's a caveat here - as your database grows, this might not prove an efficient way of working. You'll likely be better off setting up a separate model for links, with a one-to-many relationship between languages and links.

For example:

```
# langage.rb
has_many :links

# link.rb
belongs_to :language

# your controller
@languages = Language.includes(:links)
```

And then something like the following in the view:

```
<% @languages.each do |language| %>
  <h1>
    <%= language.language %>
  </h1>
  <% language.links.each do |link| %>
    <p>
      <%= link.url %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It's not erroring, but it's displaying (what I think are) pointers in the view, rather than the links themselves. E.g. `#<Language:0x00007fcc6522a900>`

Comment: My bad - I got lost in the `language.language` problem. I've updated my answer to reflect this and it should be working now.

Comment: I think it's close, but now it says `undefined method 'language' for #<Array:0x00007fcc65188bc8>` and highlights `<%= language.language %>` in the error message. I'm confused because I thought your code would work, it looks correct to me

Comment: It works! (small change of `<%= language %>` to `<%= language_name %>` -thanks so much!!!

Comment: Got it @user5783745 - my apologies, my db was updating so I couldn't test and was coding blind :) See the updated answer: `@languages` will be a hash with language names as keys, and the languages of that name as values. Note it's now `Language.all.group_by(&:language)` and the updated view code.

Comment: Great, really glad it's working @user5783745. Would like to give a gentle nudge to update based on the answer's suggestions, namely renaming `language.language` to `language.name` and separting into separate language and link models. In the long run, IMHO, it'll make life a lot easier.